# Continuous function whose square is strictly positive.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f^2$ > 0. Show that either $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$.

I thought about supposing $f$ varies between the negative and positive $y$ axis and then using the Intermediate Value Theorem. I'd come to a conclusion that $f(x)$ either has to be $<0$ or $>0$ but I'm not sure if my proof would be correct.

Can anyone drop some hints please?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $f(x) \neq 0\ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right. If you visualise it, the only way for $f$ to change signs is to through the axis.